# Module parse failed: Unexpected token ./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/VideoOverlay.js 10:25

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

After installing npm i react-leaflet, I'm trying to start React App, but receive the error that module parse failed because of unexpected token.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLJ1E.png)

I tried to modify package.json like this, but it didn't work `

```
"browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],`
```

I'd appreciate the advices how to fix it

Comment: I have the same issue. did you solved it? please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75702898/react-leaflet-module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-1025

Comment: no, I used https://pigeon-maps.js.org/ instead